# Why pthread_mutex_lock is used, when the same can be done in a programmable way?

Tags: linux, pthreads, critical-section

We all know about semaphore and critical section problem.

In pthreads, this can be sorted by using `pthread_mutex_lock( )` and `pthread_mutex_unlock( )`.

But why do we need these system calls, when the same can be implemented in the code, by doing something like:

```
flag = 0;
if (flag) // Thread1 enters and makes flag = 0
{
   flag = 0; // On entering critical section, flag is made 0 so that others can't enter
  // do some critical section operation
  flag = 1;
}
// Thread1 exits
```

Doing the same as above, will it solve the critical section problem? If no, then why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably many reasons why `pthread_mutex` objects and APIs that manipulate those objects are used instead of everyone coding up their own synchronization primitives.  A coupl eof the more important ones:

- much like many other objects and functionality that are useful to a wide audience, it makes sense to standardize that functionality so that people don't have to reinvent the wheel and so they can use and recognize standard patterns and idioms. In other words, there are pthread mutex APIs for the same reason there are standard string manipulation functions.
- synchronization techniques are notoriously complicated and difficult to get right.  So it's best to have a vetted library of code that performs this functionality.  Even if it were OK to reinvent the wheel umpteen million times, having 99% of those implementations with serious flaws isn't a great situation. For example, pthreads handles issues like memory barriers and atomicity which are not addressed properly in the example you have in your question. Considering the example in the question: there's at least one serious problem; it has a race condition where two threads could enter the critical section concurrently since the test of the `flag` and setting it to 0 aren't performed atomically.

Answer (score 2):

First, if your code would work, the second thread will skip entirely the critical section. You'd have to place a loop or something there.

Also, take into account the fact that the scheduler may preempt your thread anywhere. What happens if thread A does the test and is preempted before changing `flag` and thread B is allowed to make the test and enter the critical section being preempted soon afterwards. You'll have two threads there.

Comment: `thread A does the test and is preempted before changing flag` in that case, threadB is in the critical section, and not A, right? So when threadA returns, it sees the flag is to wait, as threadB is there, so it waits. So what's the problem??

Comment: A thread can be put on hold at almost any time by the scheduler. In the scenario that Mihai describes, thread A is put on hold right after the check of `flag`. So it's already "inside the critical section" (the instruction pointer register points to the first instruction inside the if block) but hasn't set `flag` to `1` yet. Now Thread B can enter the critical section because `flag` is still `0` and be put on hold somewhere in there. Now, when thread A is then resumed, it can run in parallel to B inside the critical section.

Comment: Also, that's not the only problem with your solution. There are two more important ones: As long as `flag` is not declared `volatile`, the compiler is allowed to cache the value of `flag` in a register for optimization, which means that thread B would never see the newly assigned value `1` even after thread A is well within the critical section. Also, even if the variable were declared volatile, there would still be the problem that B cannot see the changes made by A if they're running on different cores and the caches haven't been synchronized yet, which causes even more timing issues.

Comment: Not only the threads can be scheduled anytime, anywhere. If you have a SMP machine with 2 or more cores, both threads can be run truly simultaneously, and a lot of funny things can happen.

Comment: @dosendoc: You mean, if ThreadA sets `flag = 1` threadB won't see the value, unless the `flag` is declared volatile? Are u sure? I think i have seen it does not happen..yes sync problems can take place.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 Without `volatile`, it's unspecified whether or not this optimization happens. It may work just fine without, then it might stop working if you set your compiler's optimization level higher or use a different compiler.

Comment: Note that with gcc volatile is neither necessary nor sufficient for atomic semantics. You need to use the GCC atomics builtins, or then the C++0x or C1X atomic.

Comment: @janneb: `need to use the GCC atomics builtins` any link for the same?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 arrowdodger's answer has the function name.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should use atomic memory operations (see InterlockedCompareExchange() in MSVC and __sync_val_compare_and_swap() in GCC).

Secondly, this code will work, but only if second thread shouldn't wait when first sets flag back to 1. If it should, you wil end with loop, which would consume all your CPU. In that case you should use something, that will cause waiting thread to sleep (for example pthread_mutex_lock()).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged you question with "linux", one might add that pthreads are built on top of something called "futexes", or "fast userspace mutexes". As the name might imply, the fast path, namely locking and unlocking an uncontended mutex, does NOT require a syscall, it's all done in userspace. FWIW, AFAIK Windows does something similar as well.

Comment: So you mean to say, that my solution will work, and no pthreads_mutex_lock is required?

Comment: need to use the GCC atomics builtins any link for the same?

Comment: No, I mean to say that the concurrency primitives provided by the OS are highly optimized, well documented, implemented by experts who know what they're doing, and as opposed to the code snippet in the OP, they actually work.

Comment: Did you try google "gcc atomic builtins"? For me one of the first hits is http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html , which I suspect is what you're looking for...